# Can I pass the type of a generic variable as a parameter?

Tags: delphi, generics

I can declare the type of a class by declaring:

```
type
  TMyObject = class(TSomething);
  TMyObjectClass = class of TMyObject;
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
IData<TIn,TOut> = interface;
  IData = interface
    function GetGenericData<Tin,TOut>: IData<TInput,TOut>;
    function GetInType: TRttiType;
    function GetOutType: TRttiType;
  end;
```

Declare a base type that can give access to the generic type and give me info on what the generic Input and Output types are.

```
  IData<TIn,TOut> = interface(IData)
    ['{5B402458-22EC-4A8B-83F3-C11AC575B79E}']
    function GetInput(Index: Integer): TIn;
    function GetInputCount: Integer;
    function GetOutput(Index: Integer): TOut;
    function GetOutputCount: Integer;
    property Input[index: integer]: TIn read GetInput;
    property Output[index: integer]: TOut read GetOutput;
    property InputCount: integer read GetInputCount;
    property OutputCount: integer read GetOutputCount;
  end;
```

Here is the actual generic type that holds an 2 arrays of data. Note that the input and output does not need to be the same type.

I then have a class that contains one or more different types of `IData`.

```
TStage = class(TPipelineStage, IData);
TStage<TIn, TOut> = class(TStage, IData<TIn, TOut>);

TMyPipeline = class
  fStages = TArray<TStage>;  <<-- this is really a list of TStage<?,?>
```

I want to have a list of different TStages in my class, but obviously I cannot code that.
How do I access the `TStage<IInterfaceA, InterfaceB>` and `TStage<InterfaceB, InterfaceB>` from `fStages`?

Can I use `class of ....` in this context and instantiate an object from there?

The reason I'm using this approach is that I'm using a delegate in the Pipeline stage that is declared thus:

```
TDelegate<TIn, TOut> = reference to procedure(const Data: IData<TIn, TOut>);
```

Comment: `class of` stands on top of class inheritance. If you want to mix value types and interfaces in too, then all bets are off. I cannot even understand fully what you are trying to do.

Comment: As David said, it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. From what I can see of your code here, maybe you're over-thinking the problem and trying to throw everything at it (Generics, Interfaces and regular classes) in an attempt to solve it? It looks like what you're trying to achieve can be done using regular classes without adding interfaces and generics into the mix, by replacing the interface with a custom object list and letting polymorphism handle the rest. Your mention of using `Class Of` and object instantiation flags up potential use of the Factory pattern.

Answer (score 3):

There are a limitation in Delphi language that will prevent you to do things exactly the way you are trying. Take the code:

```
IData<TIn,TOut> = interface;
IData = interface
  function GetGenericData<Tin,TOut>: IData<TInput,TOut>;
  function GetInType: TRttiType;
  function GetOutType: TRttiType;
end;
```

Here you have a generic method in a interface. Delphi (at least until XE3) **does not support** generic methods in interfaces.

In other snipet you have:

```
TStage = class(TPipelineStage, IData);
TStage<TIn, TOut> = class(TStage, IData<TIn, TOut>);

TMyPipeline = class
  fStages = TArray<TStage>;  <<-- this is really a list of TStage<?,?>
```

The answer for the question in code is **No**. That´s an array, not a list. However, since your array is holding instances of `TStage`, it will also hold instances of `TStage<TIn, TOut>` with no problem, no matter what types are `TIn` and `TOut`.

You have this question:

*I want to have a list of different TStages in my class, but obviously I cannot code that.
How do I access the TStage and TStage from fStages?*

Actually, **you can**! It´s possible to declare a list of a certain type (`TStage` in your case) and hold actual instances of descending classes, even a generic subclass.

It seems to me that you want a generic method to return the `TStage` instance already typed to a descending type, in order to avoid a type cast and some type tests, eventually returning `nil` if the stage is an instance of another class, right?

In this case, a generic method can be helpful, but only in classes, not in interfaces. I would do something like this (I didn´t have Delphi at hand to test the code, but the idea seems to fit your needs):

```
interface

type
  TMyPipeline = class
  private
    FStages: TObjectList<TStage>;
  public
    // Constructors, destructor and other methods...
    function StageAs<TIn, TOut>(aIndex: Integer): TStage<TIn, TOut>;
  end;

implementation

function TMyPipeline.StageAs<TIn, TOut>(aIndex: Integer): TStage<TIn, TOut>;
var
  stage: TStage;
begin
  stage := FStages[aIndex];
  if stage.InheritsFrom(TStage<TIn, TOut>) then
    Result := TStage<TIn, TOut>(stage)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

Comment: `Delphi (at least until XE3) does not support generic methods in interfaces.` Correct, even in XE6 that does not compile. Thing is I'd like to code against interfaces and not implementations (as per Nick Hodges advice) but that seems to be impossible here.

Comment: OK, what you're saying is, use a class instead of an interface.